Closed Kinematic Loops in Gazebo ignition/ gazebo harmonic
I am trying to recreate rocker bogie mechanism which are used in rover designs in Gazebo simulation. Since Rocker Bogie mechanism is a closed kinematic loops these are not supported by urdf format but sdf format was supposed to support it. But from a Ardupilot SDF models it is stated that Gazebo Garden doesn't support it. I am using Gazebo Harmonic and I have tried looking for the documentation regarding this but unfortunately couldn't find any.
So is it fixed in gazebo Harmonic and if it is not are there any workarounds for normal tree structure mechanism to behave similarly for now?
Thanks

You can have a look at this discussion.
Gazebo will not accept a closed kinematic chain in the raw SDF. I have played around the DetachableJoint plugin that can connect links on spawn. It is a bit tedious as your SDF should be a tree and you can only attach links as they are relatively positionned in the SDF.
